# Image cropper not working with external images

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, crop

I am using [this](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) image cropper, which is working fine as long as the images I load are actually located in the site map structure itself.

However, what I'm trying to do is crop images that are located on an external location through a link like this: `ftp://etc/etc/etc.png`

I'm able to load the images perfectly fine into the canvas, but the moment I try to execute the JavaScript to actually crop the image, nothing happens.

However this does work when I use a source such as `images/img.png`

Does anyone have a clue how to fix this?

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: my html
http://pastebin.com/UvkiN43r

my javascript that calls the functions
http://pastebin.com/zkGpM41d

Answer (score 2):

To crop image using canvas with known x y coordinates of image from where you want to crop image :
Here either you can use the path defined by you like imgsrc="images/img.png" or any base64 data of image as base64.

```
function generateImageThumbnailArrayFromCLientInfo(imgsrc,x,y ClientInfoArray) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = imgsrc;
        var imagePieces = [];


                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = image.width;
                canvas.height = image.height;
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

                context.drawImage(image, x, y, image.width, image.height, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);


                imagePieces=canvas.toDataURL();

        return imagePieces;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you look in your browser console, you will likely find that you are getting a Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy error similar to this:

> Image from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked from loading
>   by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

The documentation for this image cropper states:

> If you try to start cropper on a cross-origin image, please make sure that your browser supports HTML5 CORS settings attributes, and
>   your image server supports the Access-Control-Allow-Origin option.

Assuming you own the web server that is serving the image, you may want to look into [enabling CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server.html).